# Change A . M to just AM

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

My App on Windows 10 works fine showing time with `AM / PM`, but on Ubuntu Distro (Zorin OS), it shows `A. M. / P. M.`

[image: Here is an example].

I'm pretty sure it is the language of the PC but I need it to be in Spanish. Either way I tried changing the default `QLocate` to `en` to see if it works, but it didn't, just change the date language but not the time format.

Comment: How did you change the default `QLocale`?

Comment: QtCore.QLocale.setDefault(QLocale(QLocale('en')))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual display of a given locale is system dependent: it's up to the user to determine how date & times are shown. To modify this default you'll need to edit your settings on Ubunto.

Changing the *default* locale in Qt just changes the locale which is created when creating `QLocale()` instances: it doesn't modify the system.

If you *do* want to display something using another locale, you can do it using the locale object. To display a date/time using another locale, you need to use the *locales* `.toString` method. For example:

```py
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import QTime, QLocale
>>> t = QTime(12, 30, 0)
```

...then..

```py
>>> cl = QLocale(QLocale.English)
>>> cl.toString(t)
'12:30:00 PM CEST'
```

Or using the Netherlands (European style with 24h clock)

```py
>>> cl = QLocale(QLocale.English, QLocale.AnyScript, QLocale.Netherlands)
>>> cl.toString(t)
'12:30:00 CEST'
```

Or Spanish generic

```py
>>> cl = QLocale(QLocale.Spanish)
>>> cl.toString(t)
'12:30:00 (CEST)'
```

If you just want to display a time in a specific format (for example to make parsing logs simpler) you can output it in your preferred format using `.toString` on [the date-time object iself](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString-3). Note though that this doesn't allow you to specify your own AM/PM markers & from Qt6 will always be in English.

The last option is to replace the output strings using standard Python string substitution.

Comment: Ok it did work, but know I got this "8:44:36 AM -04" what does that "-04" means and is there a way to quit it? (Im using QTime.currentTime() btw)

Comment: That is probably the current GMT offset of the local time. If you build the time format string yourself you can exclude that. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#toString